# Masonry leaves uniform gaps in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, masonry

I am using the well documented and usually reliable Masonry plugin from Desandro for a project.

My elements are fluid in width (25%), but on initial load, there is a uniform gap between all elements (horizontal and vertical), in IE (9 and 10). This gap (only a few pixels) disappears as soon as the window is resized and the grid reformatted.

I am already using imagesLoaded to holt the setup until the images are in place. I have also tried to removing custom fonts (via typekit) as this can cause issues from past experience.

The layout is perfect and working as it should in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.
 Also in IE8.

Comment: can we get some code or at least a link to the site its being used on to try and resolve your issue.